# Keep firing keydown event after a keyup

Tags: javascript, animation, events, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to implements movement in a 3D game, for this to work I have to deal with multikeys detection.

So I got this to work

```
    setControls(){
        this.keyMap = {};
        window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onMove.bind(this));
        window.addEventListener('keyup', this.onMove.bind(this));
    }

    onMove(event){
        this.keyMap[event.key] = event.type === "keydown";

        //Move according to key pressed
    }
```

The keydown event works fine, my object moves on two directions at the same time when 2 keys are pressed. But when the keyup event is fired, keyMap is set to proper values but onMove is called just once, and even though there's still one key pressed my keyMap is not updating anymore.

I tried a few things that got me into an infinite loop.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be moving the object within the key events. you should be moving the object within your main loop. Your key events should just be enabling/disabling values in your key map. Then in your main loop you should be checking the value in that map.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a game with input, don't put the logic of the movement within the key press itself. Instead have a "Main Game Loop" that will move the object based on whether or not an input value is set in your keymap.

Placing the movement logic within the input causes the input to get delayed so there will be a pause between the initial input and the following inputs making the movement look and act strangely. By adding it to your game logic instead of the input event you will not see that delay.

Here is an example it doesn't use a canvas or anything, but it demonstrates the point (use `WASD` to move):

```js
const player = document.querySelector('.player')
const playerSpeed = 2
let x = 0, y = 0

const keyMap = {
  a: false, d: false,
  w: false, s: false
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', setKey)
window.addEventListener('keyup', setKey)

function setKey(event) {
  keyMap[event.key] = event.type === 'keydown'
}

// Main Game loop
setInterval(() => {
  // Calculate the internal x position
  if (keyMap.a) { x -= playerSpeed }
  if (keyMap.d) { x += playerSpeed }

  // Calculate the internal y position
  if (keyMap.w) { y -= playerSpeed }
  if (keyMap.s) { y += playerSpeed }
  
  // Set the new position of the player
  // based on the internal x/y position
  player.style.left = x + 'px'
  player.style.top = y + 'px'
}, 10)
```

```css
.player {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="player"></div>
```